# update angular model from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

```
angular.module('app.services', []).service("test", function($http, $rootScope){
this.test=function(){
$rootScope.name="test1";
};
};

angular.module('app.controllers', []).controller('TestController', function ($scope, test)    {
                test.send();      
    })
```

I dont get an error but the changes don't get applied to the UI. I tried $scope.apply() and got an error.

Answer (score 0):

We need to tell Angular which *modules* your module depends on, In our case the main module is `app.controllers`.

To call service from different model we need tell to controller where is our service:

```
['app.services']
```

**JS**

```
var appServices = angular.module('app.services', []);
var appCtrl = angular.module('app.controllers', ['app.services']);

appServices
.service("test", function ($http, $rootScope) {
    this.send = function () {
        $rootScope.name = "test1";       
    };
});

appCtrl.controller('TestController', function ($scope, test) {
    test.send();
});
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/658/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks still calling $rootScope.name = "test1"; doesn't update the ui

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change ".service" by ".factory".

As I can see in the [creating services docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services)  there are 3 ways of creating custom services. One of then is using factory way, as the following:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
   myModule.factory('serviceId', function() {
      var shinyNewServiceInstance;
     //factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
     return shinyNewServiceInstance;
  });
```

Hope to help.